# Inertia group of $\operatorname{Gal}{(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p/{\mathbb{Q}}_p)}$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I want to find inertia group of $\text{Gal}{(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p/{\mathbb{Q}}_p)}$ .
It is well known that the inertia group is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Gal}{(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p/{\mathbb{Q}}_p^{nr})}$.

But is it impossible to clarify this group in a more explicit form ?

Comment: What would you consider to be more explicit? Absolute Galois groups are pretty mysterious objects…

Comment: There is some further decomposition you can do. It has a quotient that is called the tamely ramified group and is known to be abelian and is in fact just $\prod_{\ell\neq p}\mathbb Z_\ell$ and even the action of the Frobenius (by conjugation) is known. The kernel is the wildly ramified group and is much more mysterious. Neukirch's book should have a lot of information about all of this.

Comment: @Asvin, the kernel of what ? Do you mean the group of Frobenius maps which don't have fixed points+the identity ?

Comment: @Why the kernel of the map $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\Bbb Q_p}/\Bbb Q_p^{ur}) \to \mathrm{Gal}(\Bbb Q_p^{tr}/\Bbb Q_p^{ur})$. In the notation from my answer, this is (up to isomorphisms) the map $G_0 \to G_0/G_1$ with kernel $G_1$

Comment: @LukasHeger, thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using the decomposition descirbed by Asvin in the comments. Let $G=\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\Bbb Q_p}/\Bbb Q_p)$ and let $G_i$ be the higher ramification groups, in particular, $G_0$ is the inertia group.

$G_0/G_1$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{Gal}(\Bbb Q_p^{tr}/\Bbb Q_p^{ur})$, i.e. the Galois group of the maximal tamely ramified extension over the maximal unramified extension. It's well known that this Galois group is just $\prod_{\ell \neq p}\Bbb Z_{\ell}$.

So we have an exact sequence

$1 \to G_1 \to G_0 \to \prod_{\ell \neq p}\Bbb Z_\ell \to 1$.

Now $G_1$ is a pro-p group, in fact it's actually a free pro-p group of countably infinite rank (see Neukirch-Schmidt-Wingberg ([https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/~schmidt/NSW2e/NSW2.3.pdf](https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/%7Eschmidt/NSW2e/NSW2.3.pdf)) Proposition 7.5.1.)
Because $G_1$ is pro-p and $\prod_{\ell \neq p}\Bbb Z_\ell$ doesn't have any quotient which is a p-group, $G_1$ is a Hall subgroup of $G_0$, so the sequence splits by the profinite Schur-Zassenhaus theorem (see Theorem 2.3.15 in Ribes-Zalesskii), so we get that $G_0$ is a semidirect product $G_1 \rtimes\prod_{\ell \neq p} \Bbb Z_\ell$ where $G_1$ is a free pro-p group of countably infinite rank. I'm not sure how to describe the action of $\prod_{\ell \neq p}\Bbb Z_l$ on $G_1$, however.